# Is it possible to copy between AWS accounts using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Is it possible using AWS CLI to copy the contents of S3 buckets between AWS accounts? I know it's possible to copy/sync between buckets in the same account, but I need to get the contents of an old AWS account into a new one. I have AWS CLI configured with two profiles, but I don't see how I can use both profiles in a single copy/sync command.

Answer (score 20):

Very Simple. Let's say:

Old AWS Account = **old@aws.com**

New AWS Account = **new@aws.com**

Loginto the AWS console as `old@aws.com`

Go to the bucket of your choice and apply below *bucket policy*:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "account-id-of-new@aws.com-account"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "account-id-of-new@aws.com-account"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would guess that `bucket_name` and `account-id-of-new@aws.com-account1` is evident to you in above policy

Now, Make sure you are running `AWS-CLI` with the credentials of `new@aws.com`

Run below command and the copy will happen like a charm:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket_name/some_folder/some_file.txt  s3://bucket_in_new@aws.com_acount/fromold_account.txt
```

Ofcourse, do make sure that `new@aws.com` has write privileges to his own bucket `bucket_in_new@aws.com_acount` which is used in above command to save the stuff copied from `old@aws.com` bucket.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could this be done the other way around?  I have access (via AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) to a source bucket A with permissions to list and get objects, and I would like to copy files from that bucket to my bucket B, and only on bucket B I can change permissions/policies. I gave full access to user from account-A, but still get "AccessDenied  when calling CopyObject operation" error. Any idea?

Comment: what will happen if  "bucket_name/some_folder/some_file.txt" path exists in new@aws.com  too?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I have this working now! Thanks for your answers. In the end I used a combination between @slayedbylucifer and @Sony Kadavan. What worked for me was a new bucket policy and a new user policy.

I added the following bucket policy (Account A):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myfoldername",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/myusername"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myfoldername",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/myusername"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And the following user policy (Account B):

```
    {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement":{
          "Effect":"Allow",
          "Action":"s3:*",
          "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::myfoldername/*"
       }

}
```

And used the following aws cli command (the region option was required because the accounts were in different regions):

```
aws --region us-east-1 s3 sync s3://myfoldername s3://myfoldername-accountb
```

Comment: the privileges granted here are excessive
it would be better to limit them as much as possible, so others can reuse this example

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
You need to first create an IAM user in the second account and delegate permissions to it - read/write/list on specific S3 bucket. Once you do this then provide this IAM users's credentials to your CLI and it will work.

How to delegate permissions:
Delegating Cross-Account Permissions to IAM Users - AWS Identity and Access Management : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/DelegatingAccess.html#example-delegate-xaccount-roles

```
Sample S3 policy for delegation:

{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement" : {
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Sid":"AccountBAccess1",
      "Principal" : {
          "AWS":"111122223333"
      },
      "Action":"s3:*",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
   }
}
```

When you do this on production setups, be more restrictive in the permissions. If your need is to copy from a bucket to another. Then on one side, you need to give only List and Get (not Put)

Comment: Why IAM user is needed? Just make copy between buckets with read permission.

Comment: Without IAM, you will have to give the full account credential (aws id and secret) to the CLI. It is better to avoid this in the "principle of least privilege" - Hence IAM is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In my case below mentioned command will work, hope so this will work for you as well. I have two different AWS accounts in different regions, and I want to copy my old bucket content into new one bucket. I have AWS CLI configured with two profiles.

Used the following aws cli command:

```
aws s3 cp --profile <profile1> s3://source_bucket_path/ --profile <profile2> s3://destination_bucket_path/ --grants read=uri=http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers --recursive
```

Comment: Can you actually use multiple `--profile` switches in a single command? It doesn't seem to work for me, and I can't find any mention of this in the docs.

Comment: Does not work. It returns: "fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden"