# Copying between diffrent Accounts S3 Buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

*copying Between different Accounts  S3 Buckets*

I have 2 AWS accounts:

1 - Account A (For Company A) Primery

1 - Account B (For Company B)

I have data on S3 Bucket of Comapny A, that I would want to copy to S3 Bucket belongs to company B.

Let me know the setps using commands prompt and aws console as well ?

Once that data copying done from source S3 bucket to destination s3 bucket , I need to sync it on daily bases after production hours.

I would want to automate that sync process.

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: This question may help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263369/is-it-possible-to-copy-between-aws-accounts-using-aws-cli

Comment: See the duplicate question for configuration. To sync on a daily basis, you could run the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command `aws s3 sync...` on a schedule. You could run this on your own computer or on an Amazon EC2 instance.