# Python: Syncing between two s3 buckets in different accounts when I can't modify the source bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is a similar question to this: [Is it possible to copy between AWS accounts using AWS CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263369/is-it-possible-to-copy-between-aws-accounts-using-aws-cli)  The difference is, I want to do this in python code, and I can't change the s3 bucket policies in the source bucket (it's owned by a 3rd party).  I do have the credentials to both buckets.

How do I run a sync command between these two buckets in python code?

Answer (score 0):

To directly copy (eg with `CopyObject`) objects between Amazon S3 buckets in different accounts, you will need to use a **single set of credentials** that have:

- Read permission on the source bucket
- Write permission on the destination bucket

These credentials can come from either account. However, since you cannot change the Bucket policy on the source bucket to reference credentials from *your* account, you will need to use the credentials that they have provided to you.

Let's say the scenario is:

- The source is `Bucket-A` in `Account-A`
- The destination is `Bucket-B` in `Account-B`
- You have IAM credentials from `Account-A` — let's call it `User-A`
- `User-A` has permission to read from `Bucket-A`

You will need to :

- Add a **Bucket Policy** to `Bucket-B` that permits `User-A` to write to the bucket (`PutObject`)
- When performing the copy, specify `"ACL": "bucket-owner-full-control"`, which will **make the objects owned by the destination account**. Without this, the objects will continue to be 'owned' by the `Account-A` even though it is in a bucket owned by `Account-B`

Finally, please note that boto3 does not natively provide a `sync` command. You will be responsible for all the sync logic, copying one object at a time.

Comment: They are user credentials

Comment: This is very good information re: the CLI, but how do I do this in python?

Comment: Updated to be specific to boto3 rather than AWS CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in Python, like this to call the AWS CLI

```
import subprocess

cmd='aws s3 sync s3://mybucket s3://mybucket2' 
push=subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
print push.returncode
```

Or there abouts. :-) Wherever you run this from, say an EC2 instance, make sure it has the user or role that has valid permissions to access both buckets.